# Determine if Host Assembly is in debug from class library assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have a class Library, I want to log to System.Diagnostics if host assembly is in debug (My class library is always in release since its downloaded from nuget).

Tried this

```
var debug =
    Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttributes()
    .OfType<DebuggableAttribute>()
    .Any(a => a.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
```

Problem is GetEntryAssembly return null, and both Executing and Calling assmebly methods return my class library assemly which is always in releae as stated above

Any ideas how to determin from a class library built in release if the hosting assembly is in debug?

`edit:` When downvoting, please specify why. Anyway,

Enviroment.UserInteractive returns true when you are using IIS Express but not IIS so its almost what I want. But you can use IIS to host your debug enviroment too and then it will not work. Any ideas how to detect if Host is in debug?

**edit:** This is what I have now, working, but not 100% bullet proof, wont work if you debug from IIS (Only works with debug from IIS express)

```
public class BusinessContext : IBusinessContext
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;
    private static readonly bool Debug;

    static BusinessContext()
    {
        Debug = Environment.UserInteractive; //User is probably in debug from VS with IIS express
        //Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
        //.GetCustomAttributes()
        //.OfType<DebuggableAttribute>()
        //.Any(a => a.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
    }

    public BusinessContext(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        if (Debug)
            _db.Database.Log = sql => Trace.WriteLine(sql);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Which parts of `System.Diagnostics` are you planning to use? The obvious methods within `Debug` and `Trace` have conditional compilation applied which means the only way to call them if compiled for release is via reflection. Are you sure it warrants the cost/effort to make it work?

Comment: The library that hosts the code is a class library that is compiled to release so cant use #ifdebug or other compile time checks. I have a EF6 library that should output EF SQL to Output window when in debug. THe check is just done once per AppCycle so its not important that its super fast, just not ultra slow

Comment: No, I mean, for instance, that [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.110).aspx) has `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` applied to it. That means that, if you compile in release mode, any call to `Debug.WriteLine` disappears. Similarly for the `Trace` class with the `TRACE` conditional. See [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx): "Indicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined."

Comment: I do not want to listen to SQL log if im not in debug, so that wont help. Need to know if in debug and then add myself as listner to SQL log

Comment: See update for more info